# Avoid user dialog when bonding with BLE device using PIN on latest API (Lollipop)

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-4.4-kitkat

I am bonding/pairing with a Bluetooth Low Energy device from my Android app. When bonding is initiated, an "Enter PIN"-dialog is shown. It automatically disappears when I set pin from code. The dialog appears and disappears slow enough to confuse and annoy the user. How can I avoid this dialog?

I found nothing on bonding in the android BLE guide https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le.html

I was helped by this other question, however the solution does not remove the dialog.
[How can I avoid or dismiss Android's Bluetooth pairing notification when I am doing programmatic pairing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7337032/how-can-i-avoid-or-dismiss-androids-bluetooth-pairing-notification-when-i-am-do)

This question suggests removing the reciever in the SDK.
[Android Prevent Bluetooth Pairing Dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17971834/android-prevent-bluetooth-pairing-dialog?rq=1)

Is there really no way to solve this within API? Most question on the subject are a few years old and there has been a lot of changes 
in the Android Bluetooth API recently. I am currently using API 19 (4.4 Kitkat) but I would use API 22 (5.1 Lollipop) if that would help.

This is how I do the bonding:

```
myBluetoothDevice.createBond();
```

I then listen for the pairing intent to be able to provide the pin at the right moment. I also listen for bonding intent.

```
//Register before calling createBond
context.registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_BOND_STATE_CHANGED));
context.registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_PAIRING_REQUEST));

//The recievers
final BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String action = intent.getAction();        

    if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_PAIRING_REQUEST.equals(action))
    {
    BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
        byte[] pin = convertPinToBytes("111111"); //convertPinToBytes for some reason not available in API, so I made a copy
        device.setPin(pin);
    }

    if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_BOND_STATE_CHANGED.equals(action)) {
        if (BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDED == device.getBondState())
        {
            //Success!
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any specific reason you use pin pairing and not just "just works" pairing? Then you don't need any dialog.

Comment: @Emil, I want to avoid other phones, without the provided app, connecting to my device (or at least make it more difficult). Having known how much trouble this dialog would cause, I would have let the user enter the pin manually.

Comment: I think that is not the correct way to go. Instead send something on some characteristics only you know about.

Comment: I have exactly same problem, may be you can go this way : get callback from Android's Bluetooth pairing notification and handle anythings there. please share any other solution. i need open custom dialog for user to enter name + pin for ble device and after bonded, i wanna save data in local database.